# How to share static files across solution in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm developing a solution containg multiple web projects that share static content like javascript files.

I've done some research and it seems that proper way of handling it is to add shared files as solution items and then add them as links to web projects:

[image]

Then web projects should implement copying these files to output directory (I set them to Content beforehand):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  ...
  <Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" 
          DestinationFiles="%(Content.Link)" 
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" 
          ContinueOnError="true" 
          Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
  </Target>  
</Project>
```

Unfortunetely it doesn't work. I tried installing the `MSBuild.WebApplication.CopyContentLinkedFiles` NuGet package, but it didn't help.

I tried setting `Copy to output directory` property to `Always` which make them present in the build:

[image]

[image]

However scripts were still missing after launching the app from VS:

[image]

How can I make this work? I'm looking for a simplest solution possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup potentially will work for publish scenarios but for development environment it won't - the `wwwroot` folder from the project root (i.e. `WebApp1\wwwroot` and `WebApp2\wwwroot`) is used to serve the static files, so you need to copy the shared file there on build (possibly exclude it from git also for convenience).